# Flutter NowPlaying Example Provider Error

Tags: flutter, provider

I'm struggling with some flutter code especially streamprovider.

https://pub.dev/packages/nowplaying/example

I tried this code with new flutter project but it keeps throwing errors.

Can you please help me solve this error?

Error code is like below:

> ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY
> ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════ The
> following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building
> Consumer(dirty): Error: Could not find the correct
> Provider above this Consumer Widget
>
> This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include
> the provider of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:
>
> - You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.   To fix, perform a hot-restart.
> - The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.
>
>   Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route,
>   then   other routes will not be able to access that provider.
> - You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.
>
>   Make sure that Consumer is under your
>   MultiProvider/Provider.   This usually happens when
>   you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.
>
>   For example, instead of:
>
>   ````
>     return Provider<Example>(
>       create: (_) => Example(),
>       // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
>       // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
>       child: Text(context.watch<Example>()),
>     ),   }   ```
>
>   consider using `builder` like so:
>
>   ```   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     return Provider<Example>(
>       create: (_) => Example(),
>       // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
>       builder: (context) {
>         // No longer throws
>         return Text(context.watch<Example>()),
>       }
>     ),   }   ```
>   ````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There are a few things surprising me within the example:**

1. The example ommits the `create: (_) => Example(),` part.
   For this try adding: `create: (_) => NowPlayingTrack(),`
2. Make sure to add `initialValue: null,` as the provider package since version `5.0.0-nullsafety` requires `initialData for both FutureProvider and StreamProvider`.
3. Refer to [provider docs](https://pub.dev/packages/provider):

> "To expose a newly created object, use the default constructor of a
> provider. Do not use the .value constructor if you want to create an
> object, or you `may otherwise have undesired side effects`"

This also means you should not use `value: NowPlaying.instance.stream,` to create your object but instead create
a new object inside create (see 1.).

4. The example is not specifying the concrete provider type, which might cause problems. Try this: `StreamProvider<NowPlayingTrack>(...)`